# Order by 3 columns value String.Length

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I want to order my `DataTable` **CC** by length of 3 columns value. Only for one it's working:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> preCC = from r in CC.AsEnumerable()
                                     orderby r.Field<string>("Col_1").Length descending
                                     select r;
```

But I need order by `r.Field<string>("Col_1").Length`, `r.Field<string>("Col_2").Length` and `r.Field<string>("Col_3").Length` at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`ThenBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.thenby?view=netframework-4.8) method, something like this:

```
CC.AsEnumerable()
         .OrderByDescending(c => c.r.Field<string>("Col_1").Length)
         .ThenByDescending(c => OrderByDescending(c => c.r.Field<string>("Col_2").Length))
         .ThenByDescending(c => OrderByDescending(c => c.r.Field<string>("Col_3").Length))
```

Comment: Thanks @Salah Akbari, finally it´s working
            `IEnumerable<DataRow> preCC = CC.AsEnumerable().OrderByDescending(r => r.Field<string>("Col_1").Length)
                .ThenByDescending(r => r.Field<string>("Col_2").Length)
                .ThenByDescending(r => r.Field<string>("Col_3").Length);`